# most efficient way to get byte[] to Queue (ListBlockingQueue)

Tags: java, queue, arrays

I am reading an array of bytes passed in to me (not my choice, but i have to use it this way).  I need to get the data to a LinkedBlockingQueue, and ultimately step through the bytes to build one or more (may contain partial messages) xml messages.  So my question is this:

What generic should i use for the LBQ type?
what is the most efficient way to get the byte[] to that generic type?

Here is my example code:

```
parsebytes(byte[] bytes, int length)
{
    //assume that i am doing other checks on data

    if (length > 0)
    {
        myThread.putBytes(bytes, length);
    }
}
```

in my thread:

```
putBytes(byte[] bytes, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    { 
        blockingQueue.put(bytes[i]);
    }
}
```

I also do not want to have to pull off the blocking queue byte-by-byte either.  I would rather grab everything that is in the queue and process it.

Comment: is there an issue with using the [Byte](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html) type and letting java auto convert for you (not sure about performance efficiency, but lines of code this will probably be easiest).

Comment: Do you have a `byte[]` or a [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) or somesuch? Is the thing that's giving you the `byte[]` going to keep updating it as you get more data? If the answers to these questions are no, why do you need the Queue to be blocking?

Comment: The function parameter is byte[].  Basically i need to exit that function as fast as possible so i am pulling the data off and handling it in another thread using a put/take on the LBQ.
I currently have the LBQ as a Byte, but it just seems wasteful to have to loop to put in byte-by-byte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `ListBlockingQueue`. However, any `BlockingQueue<Object>` will accept `byte[]` since Java arrays are objects.

In the absence of other design considerations, the simplest option might be to just stick the arrays into the queue as they arrive, and let the consumer stich them together.

Comment: Sorry, mistyped.  It is a LinkedBlockingQueue.

Comment: That is part of the problem.  
For the definition: 
LinkedBlockingQueue<Byte[]> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Byte[]>();

you cannot do:
blockingQueue.put(bytes);  //where bytes == byte[]

Comment: Can you change the queue to `LinkedBlockingQueue<Object>`? If you do, you'll be able to place the arrays directly into the queue.

Comment: this allows me to compile.  It will be a little while before i can get it to the lab and get results, but i'm hopeful.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this:

```
    BlockingQueue<byte[]> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    q.put(new byte[] {1,2,3});
    byte[] bytes = q.take();
```

Comment: if we put different size byte[] in queue, how many bytes will it return on q.take()?

Comment: @SohailAziz - Use `bytes.length` to check how many bytes are in the `byte[]` returned by `q.take()`. The `BlockingQueue` will return the same object (in this case a `byte[]` object) that you put into it. You can check the number of bytes in a byte array by interrogating the `length` field of the array (i.e. `bytes.length`),